# How to temporarily save user input data in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have three ViewController  two of them have images and TextFields   to input from user,  and the third one is to display the first and second data and save it .

How can I temporarily save data entered from the user and when the user finishes all the required steps, a summary of the data is called for viewing and then uploaded to the firebase database?

I'm using Swift 4

Comment: Have you ever heard of something called a variable?

Comment: i know what variable but i have 13 text field and 6 image for that i need 19 variable i think  thats not good code   . thanks for your help :)

Comment: @GHAZZWAY have you heard about collections? Like arrays or dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `struct` that can hold all of the data the user can enter and that eventually needs to be persisted.

Pass an instance of this struct from view controller to view controller where each controller populates which ever fields it is responsible for.

After the last screen, the struct will contain all of the data. Process it as needed.

The above assumes the user will complete the whole process in one use of your app. If you need to support the ability for the user to start now and finish later (and the app could be killed and restarted in the middle), then this basic idea still works but you need to add code to encode/decode the struct to/from a file. Make your struct `Codable` and use `PropertyListEncoder/Decoder`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think this solution is very cool but excuse me I need an example so I can implement it

Comment: @GHAZZWAY: search for "passing objects UIViewController"

Comment: or start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: @GHAZZWAY We are not here to do all of your work. What part of this process do you need help with? Break the problem down into pieces. Start with the struct. Then work on passing the struct to each controller. Then work on filling in part of the struct in each controller. Then work on using the completed data.

Comment: thanks , but i stop in passing the struct to each controller how i do that ?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -3):

**all type of Data store in UserDefaults**

Like - Float , Double, Int , Bool, URL ...

> [Description here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults?changes=_9)

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("Value", forKey: "key")
```

Get Value

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "key")
```

Comment: but this will save data in local all the time i just want save data temporarily when user done from input all data will display and he press a button to save in data base and thats temporarily data disappear

Comment: you can store data in global variable then after click on save button to set data